# how to turn a link field into a button or link text

Tags: custom-field, links, text

```
<?php if ( bbp_get_displayed_user_field( 'youtube' ) ) : ?>

        <p class="bbp-user-youtube"><?php  printf( esc_html__( 'YouTube: %s', 'bbpress' ), bbp_rel_nofollow( bbp_make_clickable( bbp_get_displayed_user_field( 'youtube' ) ) ) ); ?></p>
  
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Hi. how can I make the "Youtube" link. Now the entire link is showing, and I want to include it in the name. It could also be a button.

Answer (score 0):

probably using a a tag

```php
$youtube_url = 'https://youtube.com'; ?>
<a href="<?php echo $youtube_url; ?>">youtube</a>
```

this will appear on the browser like this

```
<a href="https://youtube.com">youtube</a>
```